# Apache PHP5-FPM connection reset by peer

Tags: apache2, fastcgi, php

Things like this keep popping up in my apache logs.  How can I go about debugging this and/or preventing this in the future:

1. (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/php5.external" aborted: read failed
2. FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/php5.external",
3. (4)Interrupted system call: FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/php5.external" aborted: select() failed

Answer (score 2):

In relation to your "select() failed" error and possibly the others, check your version of libapache2-mod-fastcgi  There were some issues that have since been patched.

Upgrading libapache2-mod-fastcgi from 2.4.6 to 2.4.7 seems to rectify this issue.

More info here:

http://geektank.net/2008/11/fastcgi-and-dreaded-aborted-select-failed/

http://groups.google.com/group/linux.debian.bugs.dist/browse_thread/thread/3de22bc415d3da02?pli=1

However, I'm not sure what OS/Apache version you are using, but hopefully this helps you solve these issues.

Comment: FYI there is no official 2.4.7 from fastcgi.com yet. However they did release a "snapshot" tarball with this fix included: http://www.fastcgi.com/dist/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0811090952.tar.gz [ original post: http://mailman.fastcgi.com/pipermail/fastcgi-developers/2009-January/000156.html ] There is even a subsequent snapshot as well but from what I can tell doesn't have additional fixes relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors 1. and 2. today on libapache2-mod-fastcgi 2.4.7~0910052141-1.

In my case, I found something that helped - oddly enough not in the correct virtualhost server logfile, but in the general one (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`):

```
[Thu Jun 05 16:41:47 2014] [error] server is within MinSpareThreads of MaxClients, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

I'm still debugging why exactly that happened, this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761239/apache-server-reached-maxclients-setting-consider-raising-the-maxclients-settin) being of great help.