# Apache Mysql MaxClients

Tags: mysql, apache

I have running system on centos + apache + mysql with "Bitrix" CMS (Russian local CMS).

Some times system goes CPU overload and apache log message "Max Client reached". After restartig httpd daemon CPU utilisation becomes OK. ab 20-30%. 
At first i think it was memory leaks. But then i reduce mysql memory and now i have ab. 2GB free RAM min.

My apache settings:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
  StartServers        32
  MinSpareServers     32
  MaxSpareServers     32
  MaxClients          64
  MaxRequestsPerChild 5000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
        StartServers         2
        MaxClients         300
        MinSpareThreads     25
        MaxSpareThreads     75
        ThreadsPerChild     25
        MaxRequestsPerChild  2500
</IfModule>
```

on my shame i did not realize difference between this modules.
My system config: 16 GB RAM, 1 HTTPD procces eats 50-150MB, max users online 200-250 at one moment.

Why CPU goes overload when connections reaches maxclients value?
What am i doing wrong?
Thx!

htop when CPU overloads and MaxClients reaches some value
[image: CPU overloading looks like this]

Comment: after this post i found out that im using prefork
 httpd -V | grep MPM 
Server MPM:     Prefork
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"

Comment: I'm voting to migrate the question to [se], it's off topic for SO.

Comment: Find my answer and script for maxclient calculator:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761239/apache-server-reached-maxclients-setting-consider-raising-the-maxclients-settin